# How to set a default query timeout with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration, timeout

I am doing some big queries on my database with Hibernate and I sometimes hit timeouts. I would like to avoid setting the timeout manually on every `Query` or `Criteria`.

Is there any property I can give to my Hibernate configuration that would set an acceptable default for all queries I run?

If not, how can I set a default timeout value on Hibernate queries?

Comment: Are you using a connection pool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JPA 2 defines the *javax.persistence.query.timeout* hint to specify default timeout in milliseconds. Hibernate 3.5 (currently still in beta) will support this hint.

See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4662

Comment: I'm not too excited about building on a beta... Having a look at the site, I don't see an expected release date. Do you know when they're planning to release it?

Comment: The CR release is only a couple of weeks away and I would think that 3.5 will follow shortly after. JPA 2 compliance is high on the priority list, so there is no risk that the issue would fall under the table.

Comment: This timeout is working in that case, when the query is in deadlock?

Answer (score 6):

JDBC has this mechanism named Query Timeout, you can invoke setQueryTime method of java.sql.Statement object to enable this setting.

Hibernate cannot do this in unified way.

If your application retrive JDBC connection vi java.sql.DataSource, the question can be resolved easily.

we can create a DateSourceWrapper to proxy Connnection which do setQueryTimeout for every Statement it created.

The example code is easy to read, I use some spring util classes to help this.

```
public class QueryTimeoutConfiguredDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {

private int queryTimeout;

public QueryTimeoutConfiguredDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
}

// override this method to proxy created connection
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return proxyWithQueryTimeout(super.getConnection());
}

// override this method to proxy created connection
@Override
public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    return proxyWithQueryTimeout(super.getConnection(username, password));
}

private Connection proxyWithQueryTimeout(final Connection connection) {
    return proxy(connection, new InvocationHandler() {
        //All the Statement instances are created here, we can do something
        //If the return is instance of Statement object, we set query timeout to it
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            Object object = method.invoke(connection, args);
            if (object instanceof Statement) {
                ((Statement) object).setQueryTimeout(queryTimeout);
            }
            return object;
        });
}

private Connection proxy(Connection connection, InvocationHandler invocationHandler) {
    return (Connection) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            connection.getClass().getClassLoader(), 
            ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces(connection), 
            invocationHandler);
}

public void setQueryTimeout(int queryTimeout) {
    this.queryTimeout = queryTimeout;
}
```

}

Now we can use this QueryTimeoutConfiguredDataSource to wrapper your exists DataSource to set Query Timeout for every Statement transparently!

Spring config file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <bean class="com.stackoverflow.QueryTimeoutConfiguredDataSource">
            <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="queryTimeout" value="1" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways:

- Use a factory or base class method to create all queries and set the timeout before returning the Query object
- Create your own version of org.hibernate.loader.Loader and set the timeout in doQuery
- Use AOP, e.g. Spring, to return a proxy for Session; add advice to it that wraps the createQuery method and sets the timeout on the Query object before returning it

Comment: I thought of doing the first option you gave at first, but I thought "surely, Hibernate offers a way to avoid this!"

About the Loader, I'm not too excited about creating a new one in full. But I thought that maybe I can extend `BasicLoader`. The thing is, I don't see a `doQuery` in that API:

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/loader/Loader.html

So, I would have to override which methods? I'm guessing `doList`, `getResultSet`, `prepareQueryStatement` and `scroll`. Am I right?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think Hibernate lets you hook into the loader that way.  I copied the hibernate loader from source into my project using the same package as Hibernate; since my classes are ahead of Hibernate in the classpath, mine gets used.  The only downside is you have to do that each time you upgrade Hibernate. But if you can get to the PreparedStatement object before the query runs, you can call setQueryTimeout, so prepareQueryStatement might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

As I explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-timeout-jpa-hibernate/), all you need to do is to pass the JPA query hint as a global property:

```
<property
    name="javax.persistence.query.timeout"
    value="1000"
/>
```

Now, when executing a JPQL query that will timeout after 1 second:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where function('1 >= ALL ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_locks, pg_sleep(2) ) --',) is ''", Post.class)
.getResultList();
```

Hibernate will throw a query timeout exception:

```
SELECT p.id AS id1_0_,
       p.title AS title2_0_
FROM post p
WHERE 1 >= ALL (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pg_locks, pg_sleep(2)
) --()=''

-- SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 57014
-- ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
```

For more details about setting a timeout interval for Hibernate queries, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-timeout-jpa-hibernate/).

Answer (score 0):

For setting global timeout values at query level - Add the below to config file.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="queryTimeout" value="60"></property>
</bean>
```

For setting global timeout values at transaction(INSERT/UPDATE) level - Add the below to config file.

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="60" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I get an error when I do maven build, I have pointed to the query here

Can you help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613160/default-query-timeout-is-causing-exception-in-integration-test