# How to set a global query timeout for hibernate / mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: set default query timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout)

It seems I can set a timeout for hibernate queries on a per query basis, but not on global basis.  Looking at my datasource configuration and JDBC driver properties, it seems I can set a connection timeout, but not a timeout for query time (I am assuming these are different, because the socket has not timed out if the query is taking a long time?)  The best solution I have found is to create a stored procedure on the MySql server which kills off all long running queries, but I am looking to see if there is something on the application level?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout

Comment: Thanks, it seems like that property only works if I am using an entityManager and not a session factory, or am I wrong?