# Setting global query timeout in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How can i configure a default query timeout in application level. I am using spring , hibernate and db2 as a backend. Setting the timeout in datasource level is not an option as we are using an old version of IBM websphere. I tried configuring defaultTimeout in transaction manager but that is not helping. I don't want to integrate c3p0 connection pooling also. Is there any other options that hibernate provide for setting a global query timeout in application level , if yes how that is configured .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout%28int%29 ?

Comment: Yes we can set it in query level. But my requirement is to set a default query timeout in application level and overwrite only if i need some long running query which can be done by setting the timeout for that query only.

Comment: If you have some kind of helper that generates your queries, you can add your custom code there. Else, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout

Comment: use c3p0 : <property name="c3p0.timeout">1000</property>

Answer (score -1):

Here is the spring config configuration.

`<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <property name="queryTimeout" value="60"/>
 </bean>`