# BoneCP: Is there a way to configure the Statement Timeout for all statements?

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework-2.1, bonecp

I am using a play application (play-java 2.2.1, bonecp 0.8.0.RELEASE) that uses BoneCp to access a mysql database, and did not found a way to set the statement timeout for all statements (conf doc [here](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCPConfig.html)). 
All I found is how to do ir programmatically:

```
java.sql.Statement.setQueryTimeout(int)
```

I will probably end up wrapping all created statements with an object that will set that value, but I thought I could set it in the configuration file.

I know I could use spring or some other framework and set some kind of "transaction timeout" value, but I'd like to avoid that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [fork BoneCP](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/tree/bonecp-parent-0.8.0.RELEASE) and adjust the [StatementHandle](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/bonecp-parent-0.8.0.RELEASE/bonecp/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/StatementHandle.java) class to set a default statement timeout on `internalStatement` in the constructor (maybe abuse the [QueryExecuteTimeLimit](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCPConfig.html#getQueryExecuteTimeLimitInMs%28%29) configuration option for it, it is already used in the constructor for `this.queryExecuteTimeLimit`).

You can also use [JPA/Hibernate with Play](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA) which allows you to set a [default query timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout). Yes, that means using a framework but a default statement timeout is typically not part of a database connection pool.

Note that a query/statement timeout is NOT the same as a transaction timeout. A "transaction timeout is used to limit the total statement processing time to the maximum amount allowed" and a statement timeout is a "limitation on how long a statement should run" (copied from [this article](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/) chapters "What is Transaction Timeout?" and "What is Statement Timeout?").

Comment: I think you have a point when you say "a default statement timeout is typically not part of a database connection pool", so as tempting as may be, probably is not in the right path to add that feature to the framework. Probably the options are using a transaction timeout or doing a workaround in my project. Thanks!