# Set timeout for 30-40 queries

Tags: java, hibernate, prepared-statement

I want to set query timeout for almost 30-40 queries in a Hibernate Java application. Is there a way in which I can set the time out for all the 30-40 queries without using `statement.setQueryTimeout` for each query?

Comment: You can set a default timeout for all your queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
  query.setMaxResult(40); // for set bound of query results.
```

Then

```
  session.getTransaction().setTimeout(3); //set transaction timeout to 3 seconds
  session.getTransaction().begin();
```

You should pass (specify) number of query result (setFirstResult,setMaxResult) each time when you call your method.
OR use hibernate.c3p0.timeout in your hibernate config .

Comment: I think that OP wants a solution to be applied in 30 or 40 different queries without modifying each one of them. How is your answer related to that problem if they are not involved in the same transaction? And nobody mentions setting max results. C3P0 is not mentioned either.

Comment: i think he just ask about how he can make timeout in queries and c3p0 can make timeout and has many other related things to query management and connections. for example <property name="c3p0.timeout">1000</property>