# Hibernate Query - timeout

Tags: java, hibernate

This should be an easy question.

I am using *Java 8, Hibernate 3.6*

I have an `org.hibernate.Query` object and I am using it to call a
stored procedure. I am calling it with `query.executeUpdate();`.

How can I programatically set a timeout to this query?

So that when I call the SP and if the DB does not respond in say 1 hour,
it throws an exception of some sort on the Java side. Note that I don't
want to use some global hibernate property which would affect all my queries.

In fact if I wanted, I guess I would need to do what they say here, right?
I mean I would have needed to just set `javax.persistence.query.timeout`
when starting the JVM, correct? But OK, that's not what I need.

[Hibernate: set default query timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in front my eyes but initially I didn't see it.

`org.hibernate.Query.setTimeout(int seconds)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use hibernate `Query#setHint` for that. For more info please visit the [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215)

We need to set the timeout before executing the query like below.

```
query.setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", 10) //10 is the query timeout in second.
```

Note: It may also useful.

```
Statement#setQueryTimeout(seconds) 
PreparedStatement#setQueryTimeout(seconds)
```

Both has setQueryTimeout method.